# Shiny - avoid overlapped titlePanel

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to fix a titlePanel on top of my app windows (position:fixed).
But the latter get overlaid by the below mainpanel when scrolling down.
Any thought on how to keep the titlePanel above other panels ?
(or any other solution leading to a nice header with styling features - eg. align, background-color, etc.)

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMKfM.png)

Code :

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)

text <- read_file(file.path(R.home("doc"), "AUTHORS"))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    
    titlePanel(h1(id="title", "Fixed title that I'd like not to be overlapped",
                  align="center",style='position:fixed')),
    
    br(), br(),br(), br(),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      position = "right",
      sidebarPanel(),
      
      mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("text")))
    
    
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$text <- renderText({
      return(paste(text,text,text,text))})
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
library(shiny)
library(readr)

text <- read_file(file.path(R.home("doc"), "AUTHORS"))

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel(h1(
            id="title", "Fixed title that I'd like not to be overlapped",
            align="center",
            style='position:fixed; background-color: #FFF; z-index: 1; top: -20px;')
        ),
        
        br(), br(),br(), br(),
        
        sidebarLayout(
            position = "right",
            sidebarPanel(),
            
            mainPanel(
                htmlOutput("text")))
        
        
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$text <- renderText({
            return(paste(text,text,text,text))})
    }
)
```

[image]